# c arrays output error

Tags: c

Can someone please explain why this algorithm

```
for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j = 0;j<5;j++)
    {
        b[j] = a[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

gives strange output while this

```
for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

works perfectly? 
The question was Write a program to copy elements of one array into another array.

Comment: iterate through the first one and you will see why yourself

Comment: In the first code you will set all `b` value with `a[4]`..It doesn't give strange output

Comment: so what if i add continue; after the second brace of inner loop????

Comment: Mate, what do you really want? Second code assigns all the elements as you wish. I don't understand the meaning of the first piece.

Comment: ok now i got it. Im new to this so forgive me

Comment: That's allright. Please accept the answer you find the most useful (tick on the left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code is wrong. It assigns `b[0] = a[0]`, then `b[0] = a[1]` etc. Your `break` prevents the loop from going to `j = 1`.

Comment: doesn't the break statement break out of the inner loop and so that in the next iteration i increments to one?

Comment: It breaks out of the inner loop, so outer iteration does increment while inner starts over from j=0 again.

Comment: ohhhh right now i get it thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for (i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j = 0;j<5;j++)
    {
        b[j] = a[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

You are breaking after the setting `b[0]` each one iteration by `i`. So, by the end you have `b[0]` equal `a[4]` and the rest is a garbage, as you never set it.

Comment: so i should never use nested loops with arrays right?

Comment: @user2279543 No, you are not right. You can use nested loops with arrays, but you should understand what is the purpose of what you write. In this particular case you don't need a nested loops at all. Just ask yourself what you wanted to achieve by this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is equivalent to:

```
b[0] = a[4];
```